# DXA 2.0 Page Metadata

Tags: dxa, dxa-2.0

In DXA 1.7 the Page Model object had a Meta collection of the Metadata fields on the Page.  In DXA 2.0 this is empty.  How do we access the Page Metadata in DXA 2.0?

Comment: Are you using the [`DefaultPageMetaBuilder`](http://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/blob/master/Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.R2/Data/DefaultPageMetaModelBuilder.cs) in your CM-side Model Builder Pipeline?

Comment: See https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v10/GUID-69E66C18-992B-4888-ADFB-A7D00450C9AF

Comment: See also (better): https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v10/GUID-A4D0DA41-9667-4004-B711-7EED0D34EBEC

Comment: Any update on this? Did you find the problem?